# How to unwrap a drink can

Tags: mesh

I have applied smart UV unwrap to this beverage metal can, but as you can see its all over the place in UV editor mode and I can't apply texture to it properly. How can I fix it so that its better to work with?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use *Smart UV Project* for this case, use *Follow Active Quads* it will yield a lot better results for this.

[image: Follow Active Quads]

For this to work make sure you select one single face with mouse click to make it active (active quad) prior to unwrapping or it wont work