# UV unrawpp keep getting bent ><

Tags: uv-image-editor

I honestly don't know how fix this problem:
I have modeled a cola can. 
I created seams in all the right places. (at list as far as i know.)

and unwrapped the UV
and while they are no distortions on the map. the islands for some reason comes out bent when they should be in a streight line.

[image: As you can see all the strip islands having this bent shape.]
so any ideas about what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with smart UV](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/help-with-smart-uv)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically

Answer (score 1):

you could you use this addon:

https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares

it is made for this specific purpose. While the addon is free you can consider supporting the developer if you like and use it:

https://blendermarket.com/products/uv-squares/

for how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYZnGIql2UI

Comment: appearently my problem was that becuse "keep UV and mesh selection in sync" was open. so i couldnt straighten the bend UV without messing some of the other islands. by now i was able to fix this manually.
but i thanks. im pretty sure this Addon will be handy for more complex models