# UV mapping: fit image to cylinder projection

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

I want to map a beach panorama.jpg to the inside of a cylinder such that it makes a room with a circular beach wall in my virtual environment.  I've gotten this far.
[image: room with cylinder wall]

[image: cylinder projection and desired panorama]

I need to either mold the image to the shape of the map or straighten out the map so that it fits the rectangular image.  I'm still fairly new to blender so this might be an easy solution -- any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-an-image-texture-on-a-circle/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with smart UV](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/help-with-smart-uv)

Comment: Awesome! The map looks great now. This might be a naive question, but now when I add my panorama in the UV editor it only fills one of the quads. How can I make it fill all the quads or shorten the quads symmetrically to the image?  Thank you!!

Comment: You can use the scale and translate controls in the UV editor to make the image match the layout of the UV unwrap.