How to map a texture onto a "plot paper" mesh
I have some plot paper which prints along a sequence of numbers.
The Numbers are just a texture from illustrator.

I can't get the UV mapping to work in any way.

"Smart UV Projection" doesn't create anything meaningful
"Project from view" gets a little bit closer, but it is a planar projection onto the whole object, which is not how a plotter works.

Project from view:

I'm quite lost. I come from cinema 4d where this would be a piece of cake, but after watching a lot of blender tutorials, I can't figure out what's the right approach here. There are tutorials which have absurd amounts of modifier nodes, but this can't be that complicated.
Edit: I created the mesh by drawing a spline and then assign a plane to the spline geometry via Geometry options of said spline like this
I then converted the thing into a mesh because these objects behave differently than I'm used to and thought a mesh is a safe bet.
Can you point me in a direction?
Something like this:

Also, Is there a way to figure out the length of the "paper" to create a texture with the correct aspect ratio

we have no idea how you created your mesh. If you would have started with a linear mesh, you could easily do project from view and then change your mesh to the shape you want. So maybe you wanna provide your blend file so we can check it out? thx.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-an-image-texture-gradient-along-a-circlular-ring/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/how-to-unwrap-a-drink-can/

Yup, I think what you want is "Follow Active Quads". Do mind which faces are selected when you call the command

@Chris Edited my question: I created the mesh by drawing a spline and then assign a plane to the spline geometry via Geometry options of said spline like this
I then converted the thing into a mesh because these objects behave differently than I'm used to and thought a mesh is a safe bet.

Is this mesh going to be animated?

Duartes first link works for u - follow active quads

Thank you very much, folks. This can be marked as duplicate with Duarte's first link, this is exactly it.

Does this answer your question? How can I assign an image texture gradient along a circlular ring?
